# How do I run more than 5 containers in a kubernetes Pod on GCE?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I've got a `Pod` configuration from Docker that involves 7 nodes. It gets stuck in `Pending` state unless I remove two of the containers from the config. It doesn't matter which two I remove. It only works with five containers, which seems like a hard limit that I can't find documented.

How do I run more than 5 containers in a kubernetes `Pod` on Google Container Engine?

Comment: The question about hard limits seems better directed to the GCE support folks, but can you work around it by simply running multiple pods?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. It seems I can - just makes things more complicated than I'd like. The concept of pods is to group containers logically and for me, hard limiting at 5 isn't logical. One container is a logger, one is a monitor and one is a filesystem. That gives me 2 containers per pod to work with and I have to run instances of these three containers for each new Pod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure there isn't a hard cap of 5 containers per pod, so there's likely some other reason why the scheduler can't find a node to run your pod on.

You should be able find a message saying why the pod is still pending by running `kubectl describe pod $PODNAME` to see the most recent 'event' that happened to the pod, or by running `kubectl get events` to see all the recent events from the cluster.

Comment: I believe I was being limited by instance size. This debugging info probably would have told me so. Thanks for teaching me that debugging trick.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that my pods usually get stuck when using machine type n1-standard-1, It looks like it may be due to memory, I havent had that problem since I started using the n1-highmem-* variant available.